# Batch TextIOWrapper messages from stdin in Python

Tags: python

There is a third party shell script running that I want to pipe the output to AWS CloudWatch Logs. The problem is the messages from the output have newline characters in them and that ends up creating a new CloudWatch Log message for every line.  The shell script is long running so I don't want to just collect all the messages and wait until it's done. I would like to batch the messages together.  Here is the code I'm currently using:

```py
input_messages = io.TextIOWrapper(
    sys.stdin.buffer, encoding="utf-8", line_buffering=False
)

for message in input_messages:
    # TODO wait until we have all the messages before pushing to CloudWatch?
    client.put_log_events(
        logGroupName=group_name,
        logStreamName=stream_name,
        logEvents=[{"timestamp": int(time.time() * 1000), "message": message}],
    )
```